# Issue with Menu.findItem()

Tags: java, android, menuitem

I am trying to hide an action bar button, and I am having an issue with the line "Menu.findItem()", it comes up with "Non-static method 'findItem(int)' connot be referenced from a static context"

can anyone help me solve this issue?

Here is the code in question:

```
        if (ContactName!=null) {
        setTitle(ContactName);
        android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setSubtitle(HeadNum);
        MenuItem item = Menu.findItem(R.id.action_add);
        item.setVisible(false);
        this.invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }else{
        setTitle(HeadNum);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because [Menu.findItem()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html#findItem(int)) is not a static method.  You need to call `findItem()` on your `Menu` object.

Comment: Ok, so I currently have it so if there is no contact for the number in question, i want the button to be displayed in the action bar. How would i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't call something that doesn't exist. Since you haven't created an object of `Menu`, the `non-static` method `Menu.findItem()` doesn't exist yet. A `static` method (by definition) **always exists**.

`static` methods belong to the class; `non-static` methods belong to instances of the class.

Comment: Ahh ok, so would i be able to Menu as the actionbar id? And if so how?

Comment: @PhillipStanley I don't seem to have much of an android knowledge, I only answered on the issue that was specified in the question :) The above comment is out of my area to solve.